# Suggestions for implementing a scroll/progress bar (javascript)

Tags: javascript, scroll, progress-bar, progress

I want a scroll or progress bar in my web page. 
Actually, I am not sure what is a correct word for the thing I want.

By scroll/progress bar, I mean something like a video play control, where a user can drag the progress indicator to set time stamp of the video play.

I am not aimed to implement a video control. I just want a something similar: user can "set the progress" by dragging, and the bar should fire events for user's action.

1. it is not a progress bar that indicating program is busy doing something.
2. it is not a scroll bar for scrolling a piece of content.

I hope it make sense to you.

I am asking if there is any plugin or library that can make the thing easier to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin)